# Email address search by last name in Thunderbird 7

Tags: thunderbird

When I compose an email and enter the email address, if I enter the recipient's first name, Thunderbird automatically finds the recipient's email address from my address book.  However, if I enter the recipient's last name, middle name, or any other name included in the address book, it does not deliver anything. For example, the email address of `Elizabeth Liz Smith` can be only found by `Elizabeth`, not others. If the name is saved as `Smith, Elizabeth`, then it is only searchable by `Smith`. That means, whatever comes first in the address book.

On the other hand, in Gmail, I can search by any name. Interestingly, in the address book of Thunderbird, I can search by any name.

Is there any workaround to enable the 'search-by-any-name' in the Thunderbird's composition window?

Comment: What platform is this?  I am running T7 and it autocompletes on first name or surname.

Comment: @Paul I am running T7 on Windows 7. Mine auto-completes only on first name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my question. Thanks Andrei Drynov for the important help.

I have used Zindus do sync the Thunderbird address book with Google Contacts.  Zindus, unfortunately, sync only DisplayName, and does not sync First Name and Last Name.

Using other add-ons, like [Google Contacts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/google-contacts/) or [gContactSync](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/gcontactsync/reviews/), I was able to search by any name.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure, but in Options > Advanced > General > Config Editor I found this key

mail.addr_book.quicksearchquery.format

?(or(PrimaryEmail,c,@V)(DisplayName,c,@V)(FirstName,c,@V)(LastName,c,@V))

Check yours please

Comment: Mine is the same. I got a hint. My address book is actually synced with Google Contacts, which seems saving all names as "display name". I think that's why. Can I make the DisplayName search more flexible?

Comment: Check this out: http://ifacethoughts.net/2010/08/09/configuring-thunderbirds-addressbook-search/.  I think you can add (DisplayName,c,@V) to that key

Comment: (DisplayName,c,@V) is already included.  I have used Zindus to sync with Google Contacts, and Zindus only sync DisplayName, not First Name and Last Name separately. Thanks.